# Сортировка в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Допустим, есть массив:

```
var a = [5, 88, 12, 19, 22];
```

Функция "sort();" не делает того, чего ожидается.
Нашел вот такое решение:

```
function compareNum(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

a.sort(compareNum);
```

Теперь массив отсортирован. Как работает эта функция "compareNum(a, b)"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> По умолчанию, элементы массива сортируются как строки, в алфавитном
>   порядке, по возрастанию.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

> By default, the sort() method sorts the values as strings in
>   alphabetical and ascending order.

Функция, используемая в качестве параметра для `sort`, принимает два элемента массива и возвращает отрицательное число, если первый параметр меньше второго, ноль - если они равны, и положительное число - если первый параметр больше второго.