# Напишите функцию, объединяющую два отсортированных массива в один. (JS)

Tags: javascript, функции, сортировка

Не получается сдать задание на [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/573f5c61e7752709df0005d2/train/javascript)

> Напишите функцию, объединяющую два отсортированных массива в один. Массивы содержат только целые числа. Кроме того, конечный результат должен быть отсортирован и не иметь дубликатов.
>
> *Write a function that merges two sorted arrays into a single one. The
> arrays only contain integers. Also, the final outcome must be sorted
> and not have any duplicate.*

Мой ответ

```js
function mergeArrays(arrayOne, arrayTwo) {
  let NewArrOne = [];
  let NewArrTwo = [];
  let ResultArr = [];

  arrayOne.forEach(item => {
    if (item % 1 === 0) {
      ResultArr.push(item);
    }
  });

  arrayTwo.forEach(item => {
    if (item % 1 === 0) {
      ResultArr.push(item);
    }
  });

  let result = [...new Set(ResultArr)];
  result.sort();
  console.log(result);
}

mergeArrays([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]);
```

В результате получаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить данную проблему? Код в консоли браузера работает исправно. Спасибо.

Comment: твоя функция ничего не возвращает, поэтому и тест ничего не может проверить и пишет ошибку.

Comment: достаточно заменить `console.log(result);` на `return result;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Объеденяем массивы **[...arrayOne, ...arrayTwo]**, убираем дубликаты **new Set**, сортируем **sort()**, возвращаем результат

```js
function mergeArrays(arrayOne, arrayTwo) {
  return Array.from(new Set([...arrayOne, ...arrayTwo])).sort((a,b) => a - b);
}

console.log(mergeArrays([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]));
console.log(mergeArrays([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]));
console.log(mergeArrays([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]));
console.log(mergeArrays([1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]));
```

Тесты пройдены:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чисто технически код в вопросе работает точно также.

Comment: Cпасибо Вам большое, ваш код в разы короче моего) Но я так ничего и не понял:
1. Вы же тут не делаете проверку на целые числа? А в задании это есть. 
2. Почему всё таки мой код не работает? Он же всё выполняет в браузере.

Comment: @Grundy Сортировка не правильная . При такой сортировке массив [1,2,10,3]  будет [1, 10, 2, 3].

Comment: Понял. Спасибо Вам! Просто, исходя из содержания задания, я не думал, что принципиально как нужно сортировать массив.

Comment: @Vardensky В задании нет требований на проверку *Write a function that merges two sorted arrays into a single one. **The arrays only contain integers**. Also, the final outcome must be sorted and not have any duplicate.* Ваш код не работал по 2м причинам - 1, вы ничего из функции не возвращали, 2, некорректная сортировка

Comment: Конкретно в приведенном тесте это не важно

Comment: А для отдельного вопроса по сортировке есть [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/494438/186999)

Comment: Ни код в вопросе ни код тут никак не используют условие что массивы уже отсортированы. Формально они может и проходят тесты, но по сути  живой преподаватель бы за это поставил двойку и отправил на пересдачу

Comment: @AlexeyTen Данный преподаватель это codewars, а в задаче нет условия, что использование Set запрещено. Можно конечно самому написать объеденение массивов с исключением дублей, но зачем это надо?

Comment: Ну я и говорю, что формально тесты проходят, но никакой пользы от решения этой задачи таким способом вы не получили. У вас обоих алгоритм  O(n ln n), а можно линейный

Comment: А потом «ой что-то у нас программа тормозит» 